# Swift- Response Handler on Firebase Write Operations

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am following the new Firebase documentation to perform a write operation. However, I don't see any code that would allow me to listen to Firebase's response on a write operation.

Here is my code:

```
ref.child("Canciones").childByAutoId().setValue(["Categoria":song.categoria, "Titulo":song.titulo, "Autor":song.autor, "Votos":song.votos])
```

I am looking for something that would return a response for me to inform the user that the request was performed successfully. For example:

```
ref.child("Canciones").childByAutoId().setValue(["Categoria":song.categoria, "Titulo":song.titulo, "Autor":song.autor, "Votos":song.votos]) { response in
if error != nil {
//..etc..//
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
let message = ["name": "puf", "text": "Hello from iOS"]
ref!.childByAutoId().setValue(message) { (error) in
    print("Error while writing message \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)setValue:withCompletionBlock:) and as an alternative answer

```
func setValue(_ value: Any?, withCompletionBlock block: @escaping (Error?, FIRDatabaseReference) -> Void)
```

and used like this

```
let ref = rootRef.child("Canciones").childByAutoId()    
ref.setValue("Hello, World", withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
        if error == nil {
            print("success")
        } else {
            print("failure")
        }
    })
```